# Pass custom environment variables to cloud task while launching from Spring cloud dataflow server

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm trying to launch a cloud Task from Spring Cloud DataFlow Server and would need to pass some custom environment variables to the application. How can we pass the values during manual launch and thru task scheduler?

I'm able to set java_opts via param `deployer.timestamp-task.cloudfoundry.javaOpts`. I tried to set variables var1 & var2 as below but didn't work

```
deployer.timestamp-task.cloudfoundry.env.var1
deployer.timestamp-task.cloudfoundry.env.var2
```

```
deployer.timestamp-task.cloudfoundry.env={"var1":"value1", "var2":"value2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties in the following format are expected to work:

```
deployer.timestamp-task.cloudfoundry.env.var1=value1
deployer.timestamp-task.cloudfoundry.env.var2=value2
```

If this doesn't work, then please submit a bug report [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry/issues) with the exact version of your SCDF etc.,